# How do i capture the update column value and use it?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

Hi I have a scenario where in using a cursor loop getting all the invoice values and checking the details and updating flag values to 'E' if the update validation is satisfied and only inserting those invoices to another table which doesn't satisfy the update statement.

Is there a way by which based on the flag value we can insert those invoices?

Kindly find the Code:

```
Procedure 
 CURSOR c2
      IS
         SELECT *
           FROM invoice_tl
          WHERE process_flag = 'N';           
BEGIN
     FOR rec IN c2
     LOOP
     BEGIN

        fnd_file.put_line (fnd_file.LOG, 'The Line Number is ' || ' ' || rec.line_number);

           IF rec.line_number IS NOT NULL
           THEN

              UPDATE invoice_tl
                 SET process_flag = 'E',
                     error_description =
                        (SELECT 'Credit Memo line amount cannot be more than Invoice Line Amount : '
                        || (rctl.extended_amount
                                    - NVL (
                                         (SELECT SUM (amount)
                                            FROM ar_activity_details
                                           WHERE customer_trx_line_id =
                                                    rctl.customer_trx_line_id),
                                         0)
                                    + NVL (
                                         (SELECT SUM (extended_amount)
                                            FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all
                                           WHERE previous_customer_trx_line_id =
                                                    rctl.customer_trx_line_id),
                                         0))
                           FROM ra_customer_trx_all rct,
                                ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctl
                          WHERE rct.customer_trx_id =
                                   rctl.customer_trx_id
                                AND rct.org_id = 2326
                                AND rct.trx_number = rec.invoice_number
                                AND rctl.line_number = rec.line_number
                                AND rct.cust_trx_type_id =
                                       ln_trans_type_id)
               WHERE process_flag = 'N'
                     AND invoice_number = rec.invoice_number
                     AND line_number = rec.line_number
                     AND amount >
                             (SELECT (rctl.extended_amount
                                     - NVL (
                                          (SELECT SUM (amount)
                                             FROM ar_activity_details
                                            WHERE customer_trx_line_id =
                                                     rctl.customer_trx_line_id),
                                          0)
                                     + NVL (
                                          (SELECT SUM (extended_amount)
                                             FROM ra_customer_trx_lines_all
                                            WHERE previous_customer_trx_line_id =
                                                     rctl.customer_trx_line_id),
                                          0))
                               FROM ra_customer_trx_all rct,
                                    ra_customer_trx_lines_all rctl
                              WHERE rct.customer_trx_id =
                                       rctl.customer_trx_id
                                    AND rct.org_id = 2326
                                    AND rct.trx_number =
                                           rec.invoice_number
                                    AND rctl.line_number =
                                           rec.line_number
                                    AND rct.cust_trx_type_id =
                                           ln_trans_type_id);

              fnd_file.put_line (
                 fnd_file.LOG,
                 'Error Message if the CM amount more than the Invoice Line amount.');
              COMMIT;
           END IF;
        END;

        BEGIN
         fnd_file.put_line (
                 fnd_file.LOG,
                 'The Process FLag is : ' || rec.process_flag);        
           INSERT INTO second_table (
                          customer_number,
                          orig_system_cust_reference,
                          orig_system_add_reference,
                          customer_name,
                          locations,
                          inv_date,
                          creation_date,
                          inv_num,
                          balance_amount,
                          customer_trx_id,
                          customer_trx_line_id,
                          NAME,
                          term_desc,
                          term_id,
                          gl_date,
                          rec_segments1,
                          rec_segments2.....
       END;
    END LOOP;    
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [`RETURNING INTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause. So you'll define an array and capture the appropriate parts of the updated rows:

```
declare
    type line_number_tt is table of invoice_tl.line_number%TYPE;
    line_number_array line_number_tt;
begin
    ....

    update invoice_tl 
    ...
    returning line_number bulk collect into line_number_array;

    [do stuff with the array here]
end;
```

I would really try to get rid of the select-then-loop you have, if you can. That's row by row processing and there's a reason it's called "slow-by-slow."